# Refresh preloaded data with Sapper

Tags: graphql, svelte, sapper

I am currently learning Sapper and integrating it with a GraphQL service.

To start with an easy spot, I made a FAQ page with a simple list of question/answer plus a creation form.

```
<script context="module">
  import graphql from '../graphql';
  import gql from 'graphql-tag';

  export function preload({ params, query }) {
    const graphQuery = gql`
      {
        faqEntries {
          question,
          answer
        }
      }
    `;

    return graphql.request(graphQuery).then((data) =>  data);
  }
</script>

<script>
  import title from './title';
  import Input from '../components/form/Input';
  import Button from '../components/Button';

  export let faqEntries;

  const newEntry = {
    question: '',
    answer: '',
  };

  const addEntry = () => {
    console.log(newEntry);
    graphql.request(gql`
      mutation {
        createFaqEntry(
          question: "${newEntry.question}"
          answer: "${newEntry.answer}"
        ) {
          id
          question
          answer
        }
      }
    `).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      newEntry.question = '';
      newEntry.answer = '';
    })
  }
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <title>{title('Foire aux questions')}</title>
</svelte:head>

<section class="container">
  <h1>Foire aux questions</h1>

  <form on:submit|preventDefault>
    <Input id="question" label="Question" bind:value={newEntry.question} />
    <Input id="answer" label="Réponse" bind:value={newEntry.answer} />
    <Button on:click={addEntry} >Ajouter une entrée</Button>
  </form>

  {#each faqEntries as faqEntry}
    <div class="py-4">
      <h4>{faqEntry.question}</h4>
      <p>
        {faqEntry.answer}
      </p>
    </div>
  {/each}
</section>
```

The current script works great, allowing me to add FAQ entries directly from the coded form.

Now, I would like to make the FAQ entries list to be refreshed when I submit a new one.

What is the best practice to do this? Also, is my GraphQL implementation done the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the preload function to refresh the data:

```js
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    newEntry.question = '';
    newEntry.answer = '';

    preload().then(props => {
      faqEntries = props.faqEntries
    })
```

The approach is useful when you want to show entries that other users have added at the cost of making extra api calls.

But if you only want to add the recently added entry:

```js
  .then((data) => {
     faqEntries = [...faqEntries, {...newEntry}]
```